# Proper way to inject into a base controller without passing from inheriting one

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I have a controller looking like this.

```
public SomeController : Controller
{
  private readonly InjectableIntoEveryController _thing;
  public SomeController(InjectableIntoEveryController thing, ...) { ... }
}
```

Naturally, the dev in me wants to move the *thing* that is *InjectableIntoEveryController* to a base controller and avoid the explicit and omittable injection. So I'm creating the following.

```
public BaseController : Controller
{
  private readonly InjectableIntoEveryController _thing;
  public BaseController(InjectableIntoEveryController thing, ...) { ... }
}

public SomeController : BaseController
{
  public SomeController(...) { ... }
}
```

This doesn't compile because there's no parameterless constructor in the base class. However, if we add one as show below, no injection takes place, which fails the aim.

```
public BaseController : Controller
{
  private readonly InjectableIntoEveryController _thing;
  public BaseController() { ... }
  public BaseController(InjectableIntoEveryController thing, ...) { ... }
}
```

The only way to make it fly I've found was to pass the *thing* using *base(...)* call but that requires it to be injected, which defeats the purpose of the whole refactoring.

```
public SomeController : BaseController
{
  public SomeController(InjectableIntoEveryController thing, ...)
  :base(thing) { ... }
}
```

Is there a better way to ensure that the base controller gets injected stuff as I'd like them to without explicitly passing them from the inheriting one?

Comment: That is the correct way to do this.

Comment: What is wrong with that approach? I don't see an issue with passing thing/InjectableIntoEveryController to the base, if more dependencies would be passed then I would call "code smell" and rethink your approach and design pattern in order to meet the single responsible principle approach.

Comment: One of the benefits of dependency injection is that of explicit dependencies, which makes it obvious what "services" a class needs. What you're trying to achieve would hide those and almost certainly land you in service locator territory.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ As for "what's wrong with this" - we've had three cases of developers missing a certain dependency (for access privileges purposes) ending up with quite some confusion. And we are injecting three, four different services, due to certain circumstance outside of our control. So in our particular case, it makes sense to do make those injects implicitly. In a general case, I'm not arguing the case - you're probably right. But this is the reason for me asking. The predisposition and pragmatics.

Comment: @KirkLarkin Thanks for the comment. Would you care to elaborate *land you in service locator territory*, please? I didn't got that part.

Comment: If you don't inject the dependencies, the only other real option is to use the [Service Locator](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/) pattern, but as the linked post suggests, that's considered an anti-pattern. Of course, that doesn't mean you *can't* use it, it just means you should understand the consequences (which the linked post covers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple way to achieve your goal of not having to specify each dependency every single time is to dump your dependencies into a container class and then inject *that* into all of your controllers:

```
public class Dependencies : IDependencies
{
     public Dependencies(IDependency1 d1, IDependency2 d2, <etc>) 
     {
          this.d1 = d1;
          this.d2 = d2;
          <etc>...
     }
}
```

In your controllers, you can now simply inject that class.

```
public SomeController 
{
     public SomeController(IDependencies d) { 
         this.d = d; 
     }
}
```

Its signature will never change even if you have to add/remove dependencies, so all of your controllers can access their shared dependencies without having to modify their signatures every time your dependencies change.

I will concur with the comments, though: if this is a solution to a problem you have, then you might want to examine why one class has so many dependencies (or why so many classes all have an identical list of them).  I can definitely understand being constrained by circumstance, though (which is to say, I've used this solution myself)!

Answer (score 2):

I ran in the same problem today and read this question. The accepted solution didn´t satisfy my needs, because there is no BaseController doing the injection. Here is a solution that allows you to inject directly into the BaseController class avoiding constructor injection and all its disadvantages with inheritance:

```
    public class BaseController : Controller
    {
        private InjectableIntoEveryController _thing;
        public InjectableIntoEveryController Thing
        {
            get
            {
                if (_thing == null && HttpContext != null)
                    _thing = (InjectableIntoEveryController)HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(InjectableIntoEveryController));
                return _thing;
            }
        }
    }
```